# CSS3 Transition for Left Position

Tags: css, position, transition

I'm back at it, this time trying to tackle using CSS3 transitions in place of jQuery based transitions, using Modernizr as a backup for browser compatibility.

I'm setting up my base class with the following:

```
.box { transition: left 0.5s ease; }
.box-left { left: calc(left - 300px); }
.box-right { left: calc(left + 300px); }
```

In jQuery, I'm using toggleClass when a "next" or "previous" button is clicked.

You can see I'm attempting to add or subract from the current left value, but it's obviously not working that way.

Any pointers? I hope I'm being clear enough about my question.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm giving calc() a shot, but I have no idea what would go onto the left side of the operator.

Comment: Instead of `calc(left` you need an actual left value, meaning something like `50%`, `500px`, or any other acceptable value. The actual value depends on what you want it to look like

Comment: In looking at other posts, the issue is that CSS is in fact static and has no view into the DOM and therefore cannot get the current value of anything. I'm wondering if the solution is to use jQuery to add CSS inline that defines the transition. This way, jQuery can do calculations to determine what the value should be before inserting it into the element's style attribute.

Comment: You are correct, `calc` can only be used with preset values. But, these values can be percents or some other varying value and still work with calc

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. So, like before, I define the transition in CSS:

```
.box { transition: left 0.5s ease; left: 0px; }
```

But, when it comes time to animate, I use jQuery to update the style attribute with a calculated left value:

```
$('.box').css({'left':-(currentLeft) * multiplier});
```